# Manage resources to minimize garbage collection activity and improve performance

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I am working on a graphic design, vector drawing application that needs to render the data in every frame when there is a change. The issue is, that if the user is moving nodes, there will be changes during every single frame. This is not an issue with a tiny amount of data and is a major slowdown when there is anything more than a minor amount of data.

The reason is that in order to render I preform calculations and store data inside arrays. Then when the function responsible for the computation is done, the GC simply discards the data and next time the function is called, we create new arrays and new data.

In C++ I would probably allocate space in the memory and write to that space(over and over). I would probably improve performance that way. In languages that us GC I cannot allocate space that way. I have to do an ugly hack where I define an array as a class member and then write to that array from the function over and over although that array is only used in that one function and is not used by other methods of the class.

My questions is, what is the best way to reuse memory space in a language that uses GC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object pooling would be the major one, see here:
[Gotoandplay Tutorial](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=160)

Also
[10 Top Tips around GC](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1675)

I would also suggest you read through Grant's explanation of the garbage collection system in the Flash Player, it's quite unique, and understanding how Flash handles data is quite important to data intensive scripts.

[This presentation](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/garbage_collection_and_memory.html)

Comment: Your response and that link is exactly what I needed. BTW - it mentions using inline code instead of function calls, it should mention you could use Apparat instead of manually in-lining code.